# Is it possible to host a site over 3g?

Tags: server, web-hosting

I got to thinking about this for a while, is it possible to host a website over a 3g connection? not from a mobile device but from a full server, if you were to have it in a car, could you host the site from there?

The only way I thought it possible was if port 80 traffic was forwarded to the ip address of the server from the 3g provider, and then obviously point the DNS address of the website to the specific tower?

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty do-able. Have a computer hooked up to a 3g network. Use a dynamic dns service like dyndns to keep track of the ip address of the computer. That should be about it. Of course it'll be horribly slow and it will probably drop off the network every once in a while. Why do you want to do this ?

I wouldn't be surprised if someone out there has a web server app for your smart phone...pointless but probably pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on your provider.

If you have a public IP address and the 80 TCP port is not blocked than it's possible. You have to make sure that you get the same IP address every time or use dynamic dns as @Karthik mentioned.

Of course it would be amazingly slow because of the response times (not the speed, because if you compress the response and make it small that would not be a big problem).

Ohh and I almost forgot to mention that the upload bandwidth is usually smaller than the download on the 3G networks, so keep that in mind also.